# Compare results of two queries with CTEs and/or ORDER BY

Tags: sql, oracle

**Problem:** compare results of two `SELECT` queries using common table expressions (`WITH` clause), ignoring the order of the rows.

**First approach**: use symmetric difference of row sets with Oracle's set operators (`Q1` and `Q2` are compared queries):

```sql
WITH A AS (Q1), B AS (Q2)
SELECT * FROM A MINUS SELECT * FROM B
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM B MINUS SELECT * FROM A;
```

This approach has a disadvantage - we can't substitute queries which have `WITH` clause before `SELECT`.

**Second approach:** implement symmetric difference without `WITH`'s:

```sql
(Q1) MINUS (Q2) UNION ALL (Q2) MINUS (Q1);
```

It has a disadvantage too - we can't substitute queries which have `ORDER BY` clause.

I came up only with removing entire `ORDER BY` clause from queries and then using second approach. So, the question is what other approaches can be considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle allows nesting `with` clauses in subqueries.  So, you can nest the queries:

```
SELECT * FROM (Q1) MINUS SELECT * FROM (Q2)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (Q2) MINUS SELECT * FROM (Q1);
```

This approach should work easily if you are constructing the queries automatically.